# Springboot standalone application deploy in production

Tags: java, linux, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to deploy my springboot standalone application in production in linux server.I am trying to use the out of the box tomcat server.

'java -jar jarname.jar'

This works fine , but if I close my putty session the application is unistalled.

Now I used

'nohup java -jar jarname.jar &'

this works good and my application is not shutdown even if my putty session is closed.But the logs will not roll correctly(I have configured log4j to create a new log file for each day) in this case. So was wondering if this is the right way to do this.

I have searched several documentation but was not able to find a correct solution for this problem.
Please help.

Thanks

Comment: "Will not roll correctly" is not very informative.

Comment: You are using nohup to run your process in background so that you can close the window.

Same can be achieved by spawning subshells with parenthesis

`(java -jar jarname.jar &)`

or by disown in conjunction with the backgrounding ampersand

`java -jar jarname.jar & disown`

Have you tried with this options?

Answer (score 0):

Well I think it's better to use Linux services for running application, you can read here for [example](https://medium.com/@benmorel/creating-a-linux-service-with-systemd-611b5c8b91d6)

And if you want to collect logs - better write them to the file. 
Spring provides build-in me mechanics to do that

```yaml
logging:
    level:
        root: INFO
    file:
        clean-history-on-start: false
        max-history: 7
        max-size: 10MB
        name: some-name
        path: /path/log/dir
        total-size-cap: 0B
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not package it into a Docker image and run that on the server?

Here are a few ideas:

https://medium.com/swlh/deploying-spring-boot-applications-15e14db25ff0

Answer (score 0):

You can run your spring boot application as jar, but you need to create a service so you can execute your spring boot as daemon.

https://dzone.com/articles/run-your-java-application-as-a-service-on-ubuntu

With this, you can start or stop your application like

$ sudo service myspringbootapp stop

$ sudo service myspringbootapp start